# About asynctask

Tags: android

```
System.out.println("dealing..................");
                ShareDate.mdate.type = date[head + 2];
                ShareDate.mdate.date0 = date[head + 4];
                ShareDate.mdate.date1 = date[head + 5];
                ShareDate.mdate.date2 = date[head + 6];
                ShareDate.mdate.date3 = date[head + 7];

                System.out.println(ShareDate.mdate.type);
                System.out.println(ShareDate.mdate.date0);
                System.out.println(ShareDate.mdate.date1);
                System.out.println(ShareDate.mdate.date2);
                System.out.println(ShareDate.mdate.date3);
                //MyActivity.mdate.firsttime = System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
                System.out.println("******************")
```

In Asynctask after finishing System.out.println("dealing.................."); the program stopped unexpectedly. If delete from ShareDate.made.type=..........to ShareDate.mdate.date3....  the program also stopped unexpectedly. mdate is static and ShareDate is another class,  please help me ...    I'm sorry about the description. I'm not good at it.

Comment: Do you mean ShareDate.mdate.type? And as kevin said, please post the log cat. There is little we can do without it.

Comment: in log cat show System.out.println("dealing.................."); then it is stoped unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Is ShareDate.mdate.type related to something on the main UI thread?

You need to do everything that is related to the UI thread in onPublishUpdate(params)

Comment: no date is a class include some data and i defined static data as mdata in another class ShareDate  inother to let other class to use it and show this data in MainActivity ,but when i assignment data ofcourse it's static  then the program is stoped unexpected